# Add each div attributes in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to build an array containing some data-attributes that a div have. It looks like this.

```
<div class="myclass" data-test="hello"></div>
```

I've come this far, but not sure how to continue:

```
$('#container .myclass').each(function () { mArray. })
```

I have no idea what to with the array...

And the output I am looking for is

```
array 0
 ... test = hello...
```

or something like that.

I guess  I could take all ITEMS by just writing them and adding, but it seems like there should be an easier way of doing so.

Comment: all div have same `data-test` attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

[data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) returns an object containing all the data attributes. Could that be something?

`$('#container .myclass').data()`

Answer (score 0):

If your div has attributes beginning with the data-prefix (data-test="hello" data-info="some text.." and so on), you can store the values of all these attributes in an object with the jQuery data method, for example like this:

var myObject = $("div.myclass").data();

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution , using `map()`:   **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ3cL/)**

```
var dataTests =$('#container .myclass').map(function(){
    return this.getAttribute('data-test');
}).get();

alert(dataTests[0]);//element 0
```